# how to avoid using lock primitive to ensure only one task in the queue is running until it has finished?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

For the following code, I think using `synchronized` is expensive because thread switching consuming much resource.

```
public class Queue {
    public static final Executor EXECUTOR = new Executor(16, 16);

    @Getter
    private final long id;
    @Getter
    private final String name;
    @Getter
    private final int capacity;

    private final java.util.Queue<Command> queue;

    private boolean running = false;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private boolean destroy = false;


    public Queue(long id, String name, int capacity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    }

    public boolean append(Command command) {
        command.setQueue(this);
        synchronized (this) {
            if (!running && !destroy) {
                running = true;
                EXECUTOR.execute(command);
                return true;
            }
            return queue.offer(command);
        }
    }

    protected void resume() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (destroy) {
                running = false;
                return;
            }
            Command command = queue.poll();
            if (command == null) {
                running = false;
                return;
            }
            EXECUTOR.execute(command);
        }
    }

}


public class Executor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    public Executor(int corePoolSize, int maxPoolSize) {
        super(corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, 30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(), new ThreadFactory() {
            final AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(0);
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                String name = "queue-execute-thread-" + n.incrementAndGet();
                return new Thread(r, name);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        super.afterExecute(r, t);
        ((Command) r).getQueue().resume();
    }
}
```

Is there any solution to avoid using lock primitive to ensure only one task in the queue is running until it has finished?

Comment: If you only want to run one task at a time, why use multiple threads at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to run each command sequentially, the simplest solution is to use a single-threaded executor:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executorService.execute(command);
```

An `Executor` already implements an internal queue of commands or tasks, so it's unnecessary to add another queue to it.

The [documentation for `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--) describes it this way:

> Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an unbounded queue. (Note however that if this single thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.) Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be active at any given time.